# Identify every line in a textarea

Tags: php

If the line is to long for the textarea and there is a break I want it to put a greater-than sign in front on it to. How? As you can see theres missing two `greater-than signs`

```
> Vivamus ullamcorper adipiscing bibendum. 
> 
> Etiam faucibus facilisis tortor, 
> in viverra nulla condimentum eu. 
> Vivamus eu tellus adipiscing, molestie nisi vel, 
malesuada lacus. (wheres the greater-than sign?)
> 
> Integer cursus malesuada 
consectetur. (wheres the greater-than sign?)
> Curabitur tellus mi, tristique vel urna et, auctor tincidunt augue. 
> Cras semper, nisl sodales viverra volutpat. 
> Phasellus feugiat quam nec orci 
> accumsan gravida ut vitae risus.
```

I've tried this: `rtrim("> ".str_replace("\n", "\n> ", $str), ">\n");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wordwrap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) for this.

```
rtrim("> ".str_replace("\n", "\n> ", wordwrap($str, $cols -2 , "\n", true)), ">\n");
```

Just make sure $cols matches the col attribute of your text area. I am subtracting 2 to account for the to be added '> '